# How can I pass a javascript variable through a function with Smarty?

Tags: javascript, smarty

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function with `Smarty`. Like this:

```
$('#buttonClose').click(function(){
    var name = document.getElementById('nameSpan').value;
    {$person->addName(name)}
});
```

but it pass the value "name" instead of the real value of the variable `name`.

How can I do that to get the real value of the variable `name` in the function `addName`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Client vs. Server. Not going to work

Comment: PHP in JQuery will not work.

Comment: @Amit so, should I do that on javascript?

Comment: @MHakvoort Yes, it works. It is the purpose of `Smarty` and I used another functions without parameters that works properly combining PHP and JQuery.

Comment: Smarty cannot use client side variables, such as the ones created by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

All the Smarty code is run on the server, not the client. If you have Smarty function calls in your Javascript, they will be run at the time the page is rendered - not when the function/event is called in the client's browser. If you want to run a PHP call from Javascript, you must create a PHP endpoint such as `addname.php` and call it using an AJAX request.

```
$('#buttonClose').click(function(){
    var name = document.getElementById('nameSpan').value;
    $.post( "addname.php", { name: name, person: person_id } );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a client-side value to a smarty variable, as smarty is a templating language that runs on the server. Smarty assignments can only be done on the server-side, that is to say, from PHP. E.g.:

```
$smarty->assign('timestamp',time());
```

So what you can do is something like:

```
$smarty->assign('timestamp',time()); //in your PHP script

//in your JS
var currentTS = {$timestamp};
```

See http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.assign.php